# How to disable trackpad/mouse via the Mac OS X command line?

Tags: macos, bash, mouse

Is there a terminal command in Mac OS X to disable/enable the trackpad/mouse? I know that I can disable the trackpad of my MacBook Pro when an external mouse is connected. But is this also possible without a peripherial connected?

Comment: Checkout @SleeplessRazi answer. That works for newer macOS including Sierra.

Comment: This appears to be very hard to do in recent MacOS versions (10.12+). Why are you trying to do this though? If like me you are trying to learn to use a computer with the keyboard only, without unconsciously reverting to using the trackpad, there's a workaround: Put the cursor to the slowest setting and invert the scrolling direction. This should be enough to remind you to use the keyboard.

Answer (score 7):

You would have to unload the kexts, which would remove support for the hardware until reloaded. I don't really recommend this.

#### Disable

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTrackpad.kext
```

#### Enable

```
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTrackpad.kext
```

Comment: Does not work on `10.14`. Throws ```Unable to determine realpath for /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTrackpad.kext - failing.
Can't create /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBTopCase.kext/Contents/PlugIns/AppleUSBTrackpad.kext.```

Comment: Welp, apple does like to change things a lot between major version numbers. It was only a matter of time for this to become obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

I tried this in OS X 10.9.5

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBMultitouch.kext
```

it gives error "(kernel) Can't unload kext com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch; classes have instances" but it disables the Trackpad successfully.

Then after

```
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBMultitouch.kext
```

it enables the Trackpad again.

Comment: FYI on 10.11.3 El Capitan I found this to disable the entire keyboard as well.

Comment: @sming same here. what's the solution?

Comment: Using Sierra it works. Only disables Trackpad and not Keyboard.

Comment: I just tried this on 10.12.5 and it disabled the trackpad... and then caused a kernel panic.

Comment: Same kernel panic for me :(

Comment: This doesn't work with high Sierra.

Comment: Doesn't work on `10.14`. Throws ```(kernel) Kext com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch not found for unload request.
Failed to unload com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch - (libkern/kext) not found.```

Answer (score 1):

In OS X 10.9 I tried

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBMultitouch.kext/
```

to disable a temperamental trackpad, but that gave an error and didn't do anything. But moving the extension elsewhere, i.e.

```
sudo mv /System/Library/Extensions/AppleUSBMultitouch.kext ~
```

and restarting did the trick—though for some reason it also disabled the internal keyboard (except for the power button).

FYI, Apple menu > About This Mac > More Info... > System Report... > Extensions (under Software) shows which kernel extensions are currently active.